# Update ElasticSearch Mapping type without delete it

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this mapping type on my Index.

```
{
    "iotsens-summarizedmeasures": {
        "mappings": {
            "summarizedmeasure": {
                "properties": {
                    "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "rawValue": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "sensorId": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "summaryTimeUnit": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "timestamp": {
                        "type": "date",
                        "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                    },
                    "value": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "variableName": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to update `sensorId` field to.

```
"sensorId": {
    "type": "string",
    "index": "not_analyzed"
}
```

Is there any way to update the index without delete and re-mapping it? I don't have to change type of field, I only set `"index": "not_analyzed"`.

Thanks you.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is make a [multi-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_multi_fields_3) out of your existing `sensorId` field like this with a sub-field called `raw` which is `not_analyzed`:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/iotsens-summarizedmeasures/_mapping/summarizedmeasure -d '{
    "summarizedmeasure": {
        "properties": {
            "sensorId": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "raw": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "index": "not_analyzed"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

However, you still have to re-index your data to make sure all `sensorId.raw` sub-fields get created.